# How to get Bit Torrent Sync to auto start in fedora?

Tags: fedora, boot, bittorrent, autostart, bittorrent-sync

I am new to Bit Torrent Sync and Fedora. May I know how can I get BT Sync kicking when my machine start? I am able to sync via the browser client but unable to get it auto start when the machine boot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent guide at the [BitTorrent forums](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/23948-btsync-fedora-at-startup-and-working-start-stop-service/?hl=fedora). Esentially you create a `systemd` unit file which handles the startup and shutdown of the BTsync daemon on boot and shutdown.

`/etc/systemd/system/btsync@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=BitTorrent Sync for %i

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
ExecStart=/path/to/btsync --nodaemon --config %h/.sync/sync.conf
WorkingDirectory=%h

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start using: `systemctl start btsync@username.service`
Start at boot using: `systemctl enable btsync@username.service`